# avoid call CommandLineRunner in junit4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4

I'm working on a project using spring boot `2.1.1.RELEASE` with junit 4.

This is a command line application, that relies on a `CommandLineRunner` as "main".

The problem is I need to write a unit test that use some `@Autowired` stuff

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ExcludeCommandLineRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                                                      value = CommandLineRunner.class))
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExcludeCommandLineRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        assertEquals(3, this.myService.sum(1, 2));
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                                                      value = CommandLineRunner.class))
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ExcludeCommandLineRunner {
}
```

but there is no way for me to avoid the fact that the `CommandLineRunner` is called... how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you configured your project, you can rely on `Profile` to skip your `CommandLineRunner`. Declare a bean `CommandLineRunner` with a `@Profile("!test")` and configure your test class to start the `test` profile.

Here is a sample that works:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SkipCommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "skipcommandlinerunner");
        SpringApplication.run(SkipCommandLineRunner.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("!test")
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("I am being called");
        };
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class SkipCommandLineRunnerTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println("Test is here");
    }
}
```

> 2020-02-14 19:38:29.525  INFO 41437 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@30e143ff, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5b59c3d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7fd2a67a, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@779b4f9c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@484302ee, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@f0c1ae1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@252d8df6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@452ec287, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@410f53b2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@46188a89, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@37fca349, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@41404aa2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3c3cd13a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5cb8580, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4d174189] 
>   2020-02-14 19:38:29.586  INFO 41437 --- [           main] c.z.s.c.SkipCommandLineRunnerTest        : Started SkipCommandLineRunnerTest in 3.22 seconds (JVM running for 4.231)
>
> Test is here

You don't see the other `I am being called`, which shows that the CommandLineRunner is excluded.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Within `@ContextConfiguration` you defined your test context configuration to be loaded from `ExcludeCommandLineRunner` by Spring TestContext, therefore it will be executed.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExcludeCommandLineRunner.class)
```

Also `@SpringBootTest` annotation will search for a main configuration class (one with @SpringBootApplication (because it is in turn meta-annotated with @SpringBootConfiguration)) and use that to start a Spring application context. In your example, you explicitly defined which class to use for application context bootstrap.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ExcludeCommandLineRunner.class)
```

You should use one of the above annotations.

Solution : a) Specify other class(es) in `@ContextConfiguration`  or b) include inner static class annotated with `@Configuration` within `MyTest` class, which then will be used to load test context. In any case you need to remove `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)                                                
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        assertEquals(3, this.myService.sum(1, 2));
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestContextConfiguration {
      // define beans (for example MyService) here
    }

}
```